# Считывание программой файл, может кто знает решение?

Tags: python, файлы, list

Получилось создать окна для построения квадратов и записать их координат в файл, но кто знает как сделать так чтобы программа смогла прочитать эти координаты и нарисовать по ним квадраты? Может найдется человек которому в кайф исправить код и помочь мне сократить его (очень нужно сдать лабораторную), а то чтобы вывести второй квадрат написала полный бред. По нажатию на кнопку ОК координаты сохраняются в файл, лучше всего набирать:

```
Координаты первого квадрата: 2 2 4
Координаты другого квадрата: 0 0 1
```

Спасибо)

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.messagebox as tkmb


class MyWindow(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
       self.root=tk.Tk()
       super().__init__(self.root)
       menu_main=tk.Menu(self.root)
       self.root.config(menu=menu_main)
       menu1=tk.Menu(menu_main)
       menu_main.add_cascade(label="File",menu=menu1)
       menu1.add_command(label="Quit",command=self.ext)
       menu2=tk.Menu(menu_main)
       menu_main.add_cascade(label="Edit",menu=menu2)
       menu2.add_command(label="Input square",command=self.inp)
       self.canva=tk.Canvas(self.root,width=600,height=600,bg="white")
       self.canva.pack()
       self.xa=0
       self.ya=0
       self.xb=0
       self.yb=0
       self.xc=0
       self.yc=0
       self.xd=0
       self.yd=0
       
       self.xas=0
       self.yas=0
       self.xbs=0
       self.ybs=0
       self.xcs=0
       self.ycs=0
       self.xds=0
       self.yds=0
       self.show()
       self.root.mainloop()
    def show(self):
        self.canva.delete("all")
        self.canva.create_line(self.scale(self.xa),self.scale(self.ya),
                               self.scale(self.xb),self.scale(self.yb))
        self.canva.create_line(self.scale(self.xb),self.scale(self.yb),
                               self.scale(self.xc),self.scale(self.yc))
        self.canva.create_line(self.scale(self.xc),self.scale(self.yc),
                               self.scale(self.xd),self.scale(self.yd))
        self.canva.create_line(self.scale(self.xa),self.scale(self.ya),
                               self.scale(self.xd),self.scale(self.yd))

        self.canva.create_line(self.scale(self.xas),self.scale(self.yas),
                               self.scale(self.xbs),self.scale(self.ybs))
        self.canva.create_line(self.scale(self.xbs),self.scale(self.ybs),
                               self.scale(self.xcs),self.scale(self.ycs))
        self.canva.create_line(self.scale(self.xcs),self.scale(self.ycs),
                               self.scale(self.xds),self.scale(self.yds))
        self.canva.create_line(self.scale(self.xas),self.scale(self.yas),
                               self.scale(self.xds),self.scale(self.yds))

    

    def scale(self,value):
         return 300+60*value
                          
    def ext(self):
       if tkmb.askyesno("Exit","Do you want to exit?"):
           self.root.destroy()
    def inp(self):
        child(self)
    

class child(tk.Toplevel):
    def __init__(self,mother):
        super().__init__()
        self.mother=mother
        self.geometry('300x170+300+250')
        self.resizable(False,False)
        self.grab_set()
        self.focus_set()
    
        self.label1=tk.Label(self,text="XA=")
        self.entry1=tk.Entry(self,width=3,font=10)
        self.label1.grid(row=0,column=0)
        self.entry1.grid(row=0,column=1)

        self.label2=tk.Label(self,text="YA=")
        self.entry2=tk.Entry(self,width=3,font=10)
        self.label2.grid(row=0,column=2)
        self.entry2.grid(row=0,column=3)

        self.label3=tk.Label(self,text="XB=")
        self.entry3=tk.Entry(self,width=3,font=10)
        self.label3.grid(row=0,column=4)
        self.entry3.grid(row=0,column=5)


        self.label4=tk.Label(self,text="XA=")
        self.entry4=tk.Entry(self,width=3,font=10)
        self.label4.grid(row=1,column=0)
        self.entry4.grid(row=1,column=1)

        self.label5=tk.Label(self,text="YA=")
        self.entry5=tk.Entry(self,width=3,font=10)
        self.label5.grid(row=1,column=2)
        self.entry5.grid(row=1,column=3)

        self.label6=tk.Label(self,text="XB=")
        self.entry6=tk.Entry(self,width=3,font=10)
        self.label6.grid(row=1,column=4)
        self.entry6.grid(row=1,column=5)

        self.button1=tk.Button(self,text="Cancel")
        self.button1.grid(row=4,column=6)
        self.button1.bind("<Button-1>",self.ext)

        self.button2=tk.Button(self,text="Ok")
        self.button2.grid(row=4,column=7)
        self.button2.bind("<Button-1>",self.saveext)

    
    def ext(self,event):
        self.destroy()
    def saveext(self,event):
        self.todestroy=True
        file = open('text.txt','a+')
        file.write("\nКоординаты первого квадрата: "+ self.entry1.get()+" "+self.entry2.get()+" 
"+self.entry3.get()+"\n"+"Координаты другого квадрата: "+self.entry4.get()+" "+self.entry5.get()+" 
"+self.entry6.get() + '\n'+"------------------------------------------------")
        file.close()

    

    
        try:
            if self.entry1.get()!="":
                 self.mother.xa=float(self.entry1.get())      
        except ValueError:
            self.todestroy=False
            tkmb.showinfo("Error",ValueError)

        try:
            if self.entry2.get()!="":
                 self.mother.ya=float(self.entry2.get())      
        except ValueError:
            self.todestroy=False
            tkmb.showinfo("Error",ValueError)

        try:
            if self.entry3.get()!="":
                 self.mother.xb=float(self.entry3.get())      
        except ValueError:
            self.todestroy=False
            tkmb.showinfo("Error",ValueError)

        try:
            if self.entry4.get()!="":
                 self.mother.xas=float(self.entry4.get())      
        except ValueError:
            self.todestroy=False
            tkmb.showinfo("Error",ValueError)

        try:
            if self.entry5.get()!="":
                 self.mother.yas=float(self.entry5.get())      
        except ValueError:
            self.todestroy=False
            tkmb.showinfo("Error",ValueError)

        try:
            if self.entry6.get()!="":
                 self.mother.xbs=float(self.entry6.get())      
        except ValueError:
            self.todestroy=False
            tkmb.showinfo("Error",ValueError)

        a=self.mother.xa-self.mother.xb

        self.mother.xb=self.mother.xa-a
        self.mother.yb=self.mother.ya
        self.mother.xc=self.mother.xa-a
        self.mother.yc=self.mother.ya+a
        self.mother.xd=self.mother.xa
        self.mother.yd=self.mother.ya+a
        self.mother.show()


        a=self.mother.xas-self.mother.xbs

        self.mother.xbs=self.mother.xas-a
        self.mother.ybs=self.mother.yas
        self.mother.xcs=self.mother.xas-a
        self.mother.ycs=self.mother.yas+a
        self.mother.xds=self.mother.xas
        self.mother.yds=self.mother.yas+a
        self.mother.show()
        if self.todestroy:
            self.destroy()
    
  

MyWindow()
```

Comment: А загружать вы какие квадраты хотите? Просто вы в файле их накапливаете (их там может быть больше двух), а рисуете всегда только два.

Comment: Если как-то это возможно то сколько пользователь захотел, столько и вывел, если нельзя так, то только два

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну вот как-то так. Хранит и рисует сколько угодно квадратов. Сколько можно ввести квадратов за раз тоже настраивается через константу в коде.

В общем, используйте списки, кортежи, словари. Итерируйтесь по ним при помощи циклов. И тогда не придётся писать кучу однотипных строк кода отличающихся в одной букве и путаться в десятках переменных.

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.messagebox as tkmb

class MyWindow(tk.Frame):
    FILENAME = "text.txt"

    def __init__(self):
        self.root = tk.Tk()
        super().__init__(self.root)
        self.root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.ext)   # перехват закрытия окна

        menu_main=tk.Menu(self.root)
        self.root.config(menu=menu_main)
        for m_lbl, submenu in {"File": {"Quit"        : self.ext}, 
                               "Edit": {"Input square": self.inp,
                                        "Delete last" : self.del_last}}.items():
            menu = tk.Menu(menu_main, tearoff=False)
            menu_main.add_cascade(label=m_lbl, menu=menu)
            for lbl, cmd in submenu.items():
                menu.add_command(label=lbl, command=cmd)

        self.canva=tk.Canvas(self.root, width=600, height=600, bg="white")
        self.canva.pack()

        self.rects = []  # хранит квадраты в виде троек чисел: [X, Y, Size]

    def run(self):
        self.load()
        self.show()
        self.root.mainloop()

    def show(self):
        self.canva.delete("all")
        
        for rect in self.rects:
            coords = [rect[0]        , rect[1]        ,             # XY одного угла
                      rect[0]+rect[2], rect[1]+rect[2]]             # XY другого
            self.canva.create_rectangle(*map(self.scale, coords))   # применяем масштабирование на список координат

    def scale(self, value):
         return 300+60*value
                          
    def ext(self):
       if tkmb.askyesno("Exit", "Do you want to exit?"):
           self.root.destroy()

    def inp(self):
        child(self)

    def del_last(self):
        if len(self.rects):
            self.rects.pop()
            self.save()
            self.show()

    def save(self):
        with open(self.FILENAME, 'w') as file:
            for i, rect in enumerate(self.rects):
                file.write(f"Координаты {i+1}-го квадрата: {' '.join(map(str, rect))}\n")

    def load(self):
        try:
            with open(self.FILENAME, 'r') as file:
                for line in file.read().splitlines():
                    if line.startswith('Координаты '):
                        self.rects.append(list(map(float, line.split(" ")[3:6])))
        except FileNotFoundError:
            pass

class child(tk.Toplevel):
    NUM_RECTS_TO_ASK = 2    # сколько можно ввести квадратов одновременно

    def __init__(self,mother):
        super().__init__()
        self.mother = mother
        self.geometry('300x170+300+250')
        self.resizable(False, False)
        self.grab_set()
        self.focus_set()

        self.entry = []
        for i in range(self.NUM_RECTS_TO_ASK):
            self.entry.append([])
            for n, text in enumerate(["XA", "YA", "XB"]):
                label = tk.Label(self, text=f"{text}=")
                self.entry[i].append(tk.Entry(self, width=3, font=10))
                label.grid(row=i, column=n*2)
                self.entry[i][n].grid(row=i, column=n*2+1)

        for n, (text, func) in enumerate({"Cancel": self.ext, 
                                          "Ok"    : self.saveext}.items()):
            button = tk.Button(self, text=text)
            button.grid(row=self.NUM_RECTS_TO_ASK, column=6+n)
            button.bind("<Button-1>", func)
    
    def ext(self, event):
        self.destroy()

    def saveext(self, event):
        while True:
            try:
                for entry in self.entry:
                    rect = [entry[n].get() for n in range(3)]
                    if all(rect):
                        rect = list(map(float, rect))
                        rect[2] -= rect[0]  # длина стороны квадрата
                        self.mother.rects.append(rect)
            except ValueError:
                tkmb.showinfo("Error", ValueError)
                return
            else:
                break

        self.mother.save()
        self.destroy()
        self.mother.show()
  

wnd = MyWindow()
wnd.run()
```

```
Координаты 1-го квадрата: 1.0 1.0 1.0
Координаты 2-го квадрата: 2.0 2.0 2.0
Координаты 3-го квадрата: -1.0 -1.0 -1.0
Координаты 4-го квадрата: 2.0 -2.0 -1.0
Координаты 5-го квадрата: -1.7 2.1 2.0
Координаты 6-го квадрата: -2.0 -2.0 4.0
Координаты 7-го квадрата: -1.2 -1.2 2.4
```

[image: Скрин]

Comment: Добрейший человек, возможно как-нибудь удалять нарисованные квадраты, например с конца? Код просто пушка, спасибо))))))))

Comment: @user434841 Конечно можно. Они все хранятся в списке `self.rects`. Удалите оттуда, вызовите `self.save{}` (если надо сохранить) и `self.show()` чтобы перерисовать.

Comment: @user434841 Ok. Поправил код, добавил в меню функцию `del_last()` удаления последнего квадрата. Что-то сложнее этого просто лень делать. :)